# In dialout group for Chirp but USB port still not working

Tags: usb, permissions, raspberrypi, ham-radio, chirp

I've followed every available instruction and "fix" over countless hours for months. Still haven't got Chirp to work - ever. Cannot get USB access after following all instructions and fixes. Now getting "[Errno 1] operation not permitted". Have tried multiple systems Ubuntu 22.04, Raspberry OS 64-bit with new and updated installs. Nothing works. Have tried every method of install and most of them don't work at all. Installing versions that update don't work. Have finally got a version of Chirp installed that never has worked. Have uninstalled and re-installed countless times with no solution.
It's July 21, 2023 I doubt that anyone can actually use Chirp on any current versions of Linux?

Comment: If by "CHIRP" you mean the software to interface with radios, yes it works on latest Linux.  I'm not sure it works on RPi devices though, only full computers.  Unless you're talking about different software?  The issue is more likely the USB cable and firmware on *it* than RPi OS.  (Ubuntu 22.04 by the way is NOT RPi OS or Raspbian)

Comment: Are you sure that the CHIRP `/dev/` entry is in the `dialout` group? Watch `sudo journalctl  --follow` as you connect it.